# Multiple browser connections getting the same DB object

Tags: php, mysql

Running two concurrent scripts that I want to access the database sequentially so that each's autoincrement primary keys are sequential. i.e. running them both (instance A and instance B) at the time will lead to

```
1-A, 2-A, 3-A, 1-B, 2-B, 3-B
```

However, currently I get

```
1-A, 1-B, 2-A, 2-B ,3-A ,3-B
```

After transactions and locking tables didn't work as I would have expected I did some deeper looking and it appears that both scripts (even when run in different browsers) are getting the same connection. So as they are both in the same session one would not block the other. Is there anything I can do to force them to get different connections (changing to mysqli or PDO is not an option as this is an existing system)?

Chrome:

```
object(DB_mysql)#10 (26) {
  ["phptype"]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
...
```

Firefox

```
object(DB_mysql)#10 (26) {
  ["phptype"]=>
  string(5) "mysql"
...
```

DB Creation is done with the DSN string below. (There is some other logic in there)

```
mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/XXX?new_link=true
```

Queries RUN:

```
LOCK TABLES xxxx write
SET autocommit=0
TRANSATION START
>>insert 1
>>insert 2
>>insert 3
COMMIT
UNLOCK TABLES
```

Two Tabs refreshed a the same time:
Tab 1:

```
  [0]=>
  int(56335766)
  [1]=>
  int(56335768)
  [2]=>
  int(56335770)
```

Tab 2:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(56335765)
  [1]=>
  int(56335767)
  [2]=>
  int(56335769)
}
```

As the data shows, despite having the tables locked the data is interwoven.

Comment: Can you share the way you instantiate `DB_mysql` ? By the way, if you want to ensure that the objects are literally the same object then you compare the [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) of each

Comment: @scrowler Added DSN information. Also, checked the hashes and they differ.

Comment: There are a few things unclear about your question. Two concurrent users are probably not getting the same connection, but it isn't obvious how your schema is setup. If they're both writing to the same table, you cannot expect auto_increment to result in something like 1-A,2-A,3-A,1-B,2-B,3-B if the numbers there are truly auto_increment. Please post the relevant code doing the DB insertion. The `DB_mysql` class  looks like it probably wraps mysql_query() - the `#10` is instance-specific, and not an indication that they are both the exact same resource across sessions.

Comment: First though, we need to see the insertion code, and real table results from the insert, together with what you expect the real results to look like.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Just a quick question. Isn't that what table locking (and/or transactions) are for? So that one of the concurrent users can get in and get all their data processing done without interruption? Then the second user can come along get theirs done. Which would result in the data order being AAABBB

Comment: @paullb Yes, locking can achieve that, but the inserted order in a table isn't actually important unless you're talking about timestamps or sequential values. But your simplified AAABBB example doesn't make clear what is truly out of order in the table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The use case here is that each user might be inserting 1000s of rows into the table and I have to keep a log. I was hoping the log table could keep things in order by just storing the first and last id's inserted.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Added queries run to the question. It seems like the lock tables is having absolutely no effect at all.

Comment: @paulb: the `START TRANSACTION` is *releasing* the lock. This is documented behavior. (I've updated my answer to include the answer to the question "Why isn't the locking working?")

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes it does. That seems to be the issue. I've set your answer to "Best Answer". Thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: Why isn't the locking working?**

**A:** Based on the update to the question, showing the sequence of SQL statements:

```
 LOCK TABLES xxx WRITE  
 START TRANSACTION
```

The problem is that `START TRANSACTION` is releasing the lock.

This behavior is documented in the MySQL Reference Manua

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html

> ***Rules for lock release*** 
>  If a session begins a transaction (for example, with `START TRANSACTION`), an implicit `UNLOCK TABLES` is performed, which causes existing locks to be released. (For additional information about the interaction between table locking and transactions, see [Section 13.3.5.1, “Interaction of Table Locking and Transactions”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html).

---

*original answer to original question below*

**Q: Is there anything I can do to force them to get different connections?**

**A:** I think you may be barking up the wrong tree there. It's very likely that each is using a distinct database connection.

---

The values you show **`2-A`**, **`2-B`**, **`3-A`** appear to be string values.

If you do a `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY` on those string values, the rows will be returned in the sequence you show them being returned in.  Without an `ORDER BY`, MySQL is free to return the rows in any order it wants to. If MySQL is using an index to return the rows, and not performing a sort operation, we (almost always) observe that the rows returned in the same order the rows appear in the index.

If you are relying on an `AUTO_INCREMENT` property of a column, that won't assign the same value to two different rows (unless you are using MyISAM and the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is not the leading column in the index...)

Aside from that, there's no way two rows are going to get the same auto_increment value.

---

Or, is what you're getting in the database table actually something more like

```
  auto_id  byclient
  -------  --------
    14156  A
    14157  B
    14158  A
    14159  B
    14160  A
    14161  B
```

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` property is on the column on the table, not "per database connection". Two (or more) concurrent sessions inserting rows can perform operations that "interleave" the values. They don't have to use the same database connection.

To prevent other database connections from performing INSERTs concurrently to a table, you'd need to implement a mechanism to accomplish that. At the database level, you can use some concurrency killing table locks. But those are only held until they are released, or for the duration of the database connection. If you're disconnecting from the database, those locks are gone.

So, that won't help you, if the two separate browsers are intermittently calling the same PHP page. And even if you did have a way to get separate database connections for each browser session.

I strongly suspect that you're churning database connections, establishing a new database connection for each execution of the PHP script.

(I think you may be barking up the wrong tree about using the same database connection. You'd get the same behavior with multiple database connections.)

**FOLLOWUP**

I think you are asking the wrong question. Why exactly do you need to have the AUTO_INCREMENT id values "in order"? If that's an actual requirement, then likely `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not going to be a suitable solution to the problem. (Seems like you may be trying to get AUTO_INCREMENT to do perform a task that it is not suited to. In some configurations, you aren't guaranteed that AUTO_INCREMENT values will be ascending in the order the rows are inserted.)

Rather than requiring AUTO_INCREMENT values to be contiguous (is that really a requirement), I'd be backing up, and thinking instead about what the real requirement is. Perhaps identifying the "session" that inserted each row (having each session storing a value in a column in the table, along with an ascending integer value assigned by the client, for that session. And then you don't have to care about what AUTO_INCREMENT value is assigned:

```
 auto_id  session_id  seq_   
 -------  ----------  ---- 
   75322  3e45bf4        1 
   75323  3e45bf4        2 
   75327  3e45bf4        3 
   75325  3e45bf4        4 
   75324  f51113e        1 
   75326  f51113e        2 
   75322  f51113e        3
```

Comment: The database results are exactly as you describe with the auto-id. This is an edge case of what if two people execute the same page at the same time (this process is a bit time consuming) and there are other ways to quickly insert into the same table (this is an e-commerce site). I have a memcache at my disposal, I could us that which would require some pretty unlucky timing to get two concurrent users inserting. I would have thought that table locking would have forced the second session to wait until the lock was released thereby keeping the auto-ids sequential within each session.

Comment: @paulb: yes, obtaining an exclusive lock on the table would mean that only the database connection that holds the lock can perform INSERTs to it. But that absolutely kills concurrency. And potential for long held locks. Is the client making a *single* call to the PHP page, to perform all the INSERT operations... or is the client invoking the PHP page multiple times?

Comment: single call. (Yes I know it's bad for concurrency but it's not that heavily used feature and its on the admin interface rather than a user facing one)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The use case is that there is going to be a second table to log user's insertions into this table and the manager suggested having a start_id and end_id to avoid having to store all the ids. In order to do that the id's would have to be sequential and uninterrupted. I'm beginning to lean towards the extra field (the manager hates making already wide tables wider). Even if I shouldn't do this locking stuff, it seems really weird to me that it just doesn't work.

Comment: "If a session begins a transaction (for example, with START TRANSACTION), an implicit UNLOCK TABLES is performed, which causes existing locks to be released. "  <-- This was it. Removing the transaction made the locks work as expected. Thank you! But the transaction is a must so looks like I need to bark up a whole different tree. Thanks for all the time helping me here!